# TightVNC not running gnome-session

Tags: gnome, debian, vnc

I have a Debian Lenny box with Gnome desktop. I've installed Tightvnc server on it and would like to see a Gnome session when connecting from another computer using VNC viewer. But for some reason it opens the "X Desktop" with only a terminal window visible. What could be wrong?

I used [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#Customising%20your%20session) for editing the configuration (~/.vnc/xstartup). So looks like it's not recognizing *gnome-session &* and is falling back to generic session instead. Why?

Comment: Add `set -x` to get a trace of the script's execution. You may also need `exec >~/.vnc-startup-$DISPLAY.log 2>&1` to get the log to a known place, although it should appear in `~/.vnc/darkstar:9` without the `exec` line (where `darkstar` is your hostname and `9` is the display number). Post the trace in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it wasn't a production box I just removed and then re-installed Gnome desktop environment. After that RealVNC works without problems with Gnome. @Gilles - I came back here after the reinstall was already done so problem was solved. But thanks for the advice.